# "Turn out" and "turn out to be "

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "turn out" instead of "turn out to be" in sentences such as the one below, and omit the verb "to be" **because I've used it in the the first part of my sentence:**

> You were supposed to be an aid, **but turned out to be an impediment.**

and write it this way:

> You were supposed to be an aid, **but turned out an impediment.**

Personally I think I cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit 'to be' in sentences using the phrasal verb 'turn out'. It may be thought a little old-fashioned.

> The son on whom he has pinned his heart and hopes has turned out a
> good-for-nothing rotter.
>
> His father, who was a carpenter, bore the character of an honest man;
> yet he had another son, named Thomas, who as well as Jack, turned out
> a thief.
>
> He turned out a friend, helping me to take up a good property in the Ultima District.

Comment: Agree that this sounds old-fashioned.

Comment: @nschneid - in the UK we still say 'it has turned out nice today' if the weather is fine.

Comment: What about "It has turned out a nice day"?

Comment: @nschneid - yes, nothing wrong with that. Or a miserable, memorable, tiring, joyful, or interesting day.